# Bursting baloon is timing out in leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, memoization

> Given n balloons, indexed from 0 to n-1. Each balloon is painted with a number on it represented by array nums. You are asked to burst all the balloons. If the you burst balloon i you will get nums[left] * nums[i] * nums[right] coins. Here left and right are adjacent indices of i. After the burst, the left and right then becomes adjacent.
>
> Find the maximum coins you can collect by bursting the balloons wisely.
>
> nums = [3,1,5,8] --> [3,5,8] -->   [3,8]   -->  [8]  --> []
>      coins =  3*1*5      +  3*5*8    +  1*3*8      + 1*8*1   = 167

I am getting time out for some of the test cases.

Wondering how to improve? Please just give me **hints** only.

```
class Solution(object):
        def recursion(self, nums, index, dp):
            r = -1
            if not nums:
                return 0
            if len(nums) == 1:
                return nums[0]
            if str(nums) in dp:
                return dp[str(nums)]
            if index >= len(nums):
                return 0
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                if i == 0:
                    r = max(r, nums[i]*nums[i+1] + self.recursion(nums[0:i]+nums[i+1:][:], i, dp))
                elif i == len(nums)-1:
                    r = max(r, nums[i-1]*nums[i] + self.recursion(nums[0:i]+nums[i+1:][:], i, dp))
                else:
                    r = max(r, nums[i-1]*nums[i]*nums[i+1] + self.recursion(nums[0:i]+nums[i+1:][:], i, dp))
            dp[str(nums)] = r
            return r

        def maxCoins(self, nums):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :rtype: int
            """
            return self.recursion(nums, 0, {})
```

Comment: Perhaps DP solution of `matrix chain multiplication` problem might give some ideas

Comment: If the code works, you could post it on Codereview as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: try to avoid copying the list in each recursion.

p.s.: I'm pretty sure there's a dynamic programming solution that has a time complexity of O(n^3).